# Clojure sequences and collections

Tags: clojure, lisp, lazy-evaluation, cons

In Lisp all data structures builds of *cons cells*, i.e they are essentially linked lists or binary trees or both (correct me if I'm wrong). Clojure data structures are *lists*, *vectors*, *maps* and *sets*. Clojure incorporates two inclusive abstractions for these data structures: *collections* and *sequences*. *Sequence* abstraction defines `first`, `rest` and `cons` operations, where as *collection* abstraction define collection specific operations such as `conj` and `into`.

Clojure core functions such as `map` and `filter` operates on *sequence* abstraction but accepts any data structure and performs implicit conversion. These functions are also lazy. Does this mean by default Clojure internally stores data in more efficient data structures such as indexed arrays and only switches to linked lists as needed? How does Clojure actually convert collections to sequences? Is the sequence built from collection using iterator in a streaming fashion or as a whole and then passed to the consumer?

Comment: "In Lisp all data structures builds of cons cells" - That's a common misconception, but all lisps (except some toy lisps) have other data structures too.

Answer (score 2):

The only data structure in Clojure that is a singly-linked list is an actual `list` like:

```
(list 1 2 3)
```

Everything else is an efficient data structure (i.e. vector, map).

A lazy-sequence is (nominally) composed of the current value and a recipe for generating the next value.  Once computed, elements are cached and are not re-computed.

Conversion of a collection to a sequence is an implementation detail and is not normally important to the end user.

The original `map` and `filter` functions are lazy, as are many others.  However, this was enough of a headache (unpredictable time of realization) that eager/imperative versions `mapv` and `filterv` were added to the language.

Comment: A `clojure.lang.Cons`, such as `cons` creates, is a linked list, as [the source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Cons.java) shows. A [`clojure.lang.persistentList`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentList.java) is a different linked list: for example it is counted, whereas `clojure.lang.Cons` is not.